# List.Find() issue

Tags: c#, list

I am wondering why I have this problem with my list.

I am trying to retrieve the object for the previous index, so -1;

Is that the good way to do ?

```
thePreviousList.Find(previousItem => previousItem.Id - 1);
```

Comment: Previous *index*, or previous *ID*? Please give more context.

Comment: Previous Id . Wich is also index in the list because it starts to 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the best way is to use the index:

```
var item = thePreviousList[indexofItem];
var previousItem = thePreviousList[indexofItem -1];
```

But probably i've misunderstood your requirement.

If you want to find an item by it's ID(assuming that it has this property):

```
var idToFind=4711;
var thisIndex = thePreviousList.Where((i, index) => i.ID==idToFind)
                   .Select((i, index) => index).FirstOrDefault();
if(thisIndex > 0)
{
    var previousItem = thePreviousList[thisIndex - 1];
}
```

Comment: Only assertion is required for `(indexOfItem == 0)` :)

Comment: Basically I just add an object to my list with an Id . And then when I load the page I would like to retrieve not the last object in the list , but the one just before .

Comment: But that might change when the order will change. This sounds like there would be another,better approach for what you're trying. Relying on a index is rarely robust.

Answer (score 0):

Find
Works with predicates ([msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28%22SYSTEM.COLLECTIONS.GENERIC.LIST%601.FIND%22%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22.NETFRAMEWORK%2cVERSION%3dV2.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true))

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want:

```
if (currentItem.ID != 0)
{
    var previousItem = list[currentItem.ID - 1];
    // Use previous item...
}
else
{
    // This was the first item in the list.
}
```

No need to go over the whole list, if you're *sure* that the ID matches the index in the list.

Comment: When i do this    PreviousItem theItem = new PreviousItem();

                    theItem = thePreviousList[countIdPrevious - 1];


                    previousFolderName = theItem.oldProjectName;
                    previousFolderId = theItem.oldProjectId;

Comment: previsouFolderName and previousFolderId are not implemented .. ?

Comment: @Emged: Um, if you haven't declared the variables, how would you expect it to work? And why are you creating a `new PreviousItem()` and then immediately throw it away? It sounds like you're somewhat confused about how C# works to start with. (If this was your downvote by the way, please could you explain it?)

Comment: They are declared , I just didn't copy all my code ! 
And I didn't down vote anything don't worry !

Comment: @Emged: If they're declared, then it should be fine. Please give the *exact* error message.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by the comment you made on Tim's answer, you want something like the following:

```
thePreviousList.ElementAt(thePreviousList.Count - 2);
```

Note that the -2 is because your indexing (used by ElementAt) is 0 based (that justifies -1) and then you want the penultimate element (another -1).